# Appscript: Timestamp a Column when a certain cell Changes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet that has a 2 buttons that changes a certain cell (K3) to a ON or Off (text)
I need to time stamp in column (Z) every time K3 changes to On
and to time stamp in column (AA) every time K3 changes to Off

or in a simpler way to time stamp every time I click on the On button in column Z , and when clicking the Off button timestamps in column AA

Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Can you share you sheet and what you've tried so far?